# Pigeonhole proof of the existence of two numbers with given sum

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory, pigeonhole-principle

> Let $|W|=m+1$ and $W$ be a subset of $X=\{1,2,3,\dots ,2m\}$ ($m$ is any natural number).
>   Prove there exists two numbers in $W$ whose sum is $2m+1$.

Can anyone give me a hint to prove this? I know I should be using the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Is $n$ supposed to be $m$?

Comment: Any $m + 1$ sized subset $X$ of $\{1, ..., 2m\}$, the smallest possible value for the large element of $X$ is $m + 1$. The smallest possible value for the second largest element of $x$ is $m$.

Comment: Put $x$ and $y$ in the same pigeonhole if $x+y=2m+1$. There are $m$ pigeonholes.

Answer (score 0):

There are $m$ **disjoint** pairs of elements $a,b\in{X}$ such that $a+b=2m+1$:

- $1,2m-0$
- $2,2m-1$
- $3,2m-2$
- $\dots$
- $m,m+1$

Since $W$ consists of $m+1$ elements, at least one of these pairs must be in it.